# TypeError: Cannot set property 'usingClientEntryPoint' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library, react-18

In react-18.0.0 version app I'm writing test case for index.js file I'm getting following error

● Application root › should render without crashing

```
TypeError: Cannot set property 'usingClientEntryPoint' of undefined

   5 | import reportWebVitals from "./reportWebVitals";
   6 |
>  7 | const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));
     |                       ^
   8 |
   9 | root.render(
  10 |   <React.StrictMode>
```

and My index.test.js

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom/client";
import App from "./App";

jest.mock("react-dom", () => ({ render: jest.fn() }));

describe("Application root", () => {
  it("should render without crashing", () => {
    const div = document.createElement("div");
    div.id = "root";
    document.body.appendChild(div);
    require("./index.js");
    expect(ReactDOM.render).toHaveBeenCalledWith(<App />, div);
  });
});
```

how to fix the issue.

Comment: I am also facing the same error. Strange not much information is available on this.

Comment: Were you able to solve this? Looks related to https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/24372

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you are mocking **react-dom** and since createRoot is exposed from **react-dom/client**, you would need to do this way instead:

```
jest.mock("react-dom/client", () => ({ 
  createRoot: jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => ({
    render: jest.fn() 
  }))
}));

describe('Application root', () => {
  it('should render without crashing', () => {
    // render your app here
    expect(renderFn).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
});
```

Comment: Could you please update a index.test.js file code

Comment: updated the code to have a test case